# After animating margin-left the width is doubled

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am running a pretty simple animation using jquery. I want to move div to the left and after to the right to its original position. I start off with this:

```
 var leftCards = '-'+ $(".target").width() +'px';
 $(".target").stop().animate({'margin-left': leftCards });
```

It is moving to the left. However, the width is doubled and the right hand side of the `div` is not moving....

In the layout the  margin-left=405 and the complete width is 805px....

I need to somehow move the right hand side of the `div` at the same time....

If I use

```
$(".target").stop().animate({'margin-left': leftCards,width:0 });
```

The text in the div keeps on moving....

Comment: please provide relevant HTML markup and maybe a jsFiddle

Comment: setting `margin-left:` to some value will actually increasing the width of your page. instead use `left:` .

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="target"></div>
    <button id="left">Left</button>
    <button id="right">Right</button>
 <div class="tarWidth" style="top:100px;position:relative"></div>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
var rightCards = 0;
var leftCards = 0;

// Start animation
$("#left").click(function () {
   leftCards = '-' + $(".target").width() + 'px';
   $(".target").stop().animate({
       'left': leftCards
   });
   $('.tarWidth').text($(".target").width() + 'px');
});

// Start animation in the opposite direction
$("#right").click(function () {
    rightCards = '+' + $(".target").width() + 'px';
    $(".target").stop().animate({
       'left': rightCards
     });
    $('.tarWidth').text($(".target").width() + 'px');
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7y5he/12/

Happy Coding :)